# WebView app shows blank screen after Google login

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I have read so many different articles and I just can't seem to find an answer that will help me. Basically, I am using `WebView` for my app. I am able to log in with Google, but, once I log in the screen goes white, and nothing happens. Everything works fine on my website, but within `WebView` on the app, it doesn't work. I really don't want to use webviewchrome (I think that's what it's called), I really want to use `WebView`.

**Here is my code:**

```
private String url = "url";

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("url");

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent");
    webSettings.setUserAgentString(userAgent + "appname");

    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);

    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I am very new to this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the INTERNET permission to your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes, i added that code, already